# Give Mathematica points in the XY plane and find equation that generates them

Tags: mathematical-optimization, pattern-matching

I am finding the minima of a 2D cubic periodic function by "brute force", i.e. looking for the (x,y) positions where the both the x and y derivatives are 0.

This returns a list of points, in this case regularly spaced by 1 in both x and y:

[image]

**Can I give Mathematica this list of 2D points, for it to generate an equation whose solution are these points?**

In this case, for example, I would like Mathematica to tell me that my points are the solutions to  `(x,y) = (n,m)`  with  `n, m`  in the positive/negative integers.

I am asking this becaue I have a quasi-periodic function, and would like to know whether the location of its minima follows an equation, maybe involving an irrational number.

---

Example code:

```
RealPotentialCubic[x_, y_] := Sin[ \[Pi] x]^2  + Sin[ \[Pi] y]^2;
Plot3D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
{RealMiniCubic, RealMinimaCubic, RealcurvMiniCubic, RealMaxiCubic, 
   RealMaximaCubic, RealcurvMaxiCubic} = 
  FindExtrema[RealPotentialCubic, 10, 20];
ListPlot[RealMiniCubic]
```

where the function to find the minima is defined as:

```
FindExtrema[potential_, windowsize_, points_] := 
 Module[{dx, dy, hl, x, y, hes, crit, mnp, mxp, sdp, mini, maxi, 
   sadl}, {dx[x_, y_], dy[x_, y_]} = D[potential[x, y], {{x, y}}];
  hes[x_, y_] = D[potential[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}];
  crit = Cases[
    Normal[ContourPlot[
      dx[x, y] == 0, {x, -windowsize/2, 
       windowsize/2}, {y, -(windowsize/2), windowsize/2}, 
      PlotPoints -> points, ContourStyle -> None, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
      MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, dy[x, y]]]], 
    Point[{x0_, y0_}] :> ({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
       FindRoot[{dx[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]], 
         dy[\[FormalX], \[FormalY]]}, {{\[FormalX], x0}, {\[FormalY], 
          y0}}]), \[Infinity]];
  hl = hes @@@ crit;
  mnp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hl;
  mxp = PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ (-hl);
  sdp = Thread[mnp \[Nor] mxp];
  mini = Pick[crit, mnp];
  maxi = Pick[crit, mxp];
  sadl = Pick[crit, sdp];
  Chop[{mini, potential @@@ mini, hes @@@ mini, maxi, 
    potential @@@ maxi, hes @@@ maxi}]]
```

Comment: Well, your equation is setting the derivative to zero. The solution of this equation are your points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RealPotentialCubic[x_, y_] := Sin[π x]^2 + Sin[π y]^2;
```

The minima occur at

```
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers],
  Solve[{
     D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], x] == 0,
     D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], y] == 0,
     D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], {x, 2}] > 0,
     D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], {y, 2}] > 0},
    {x, y}, Reals] // Simplify] /. {C[1] -> n, C[2] -> m}

(* {{x -> 2 n, y -> 2 m}, {x -> 2 n, y -> 1 + 2 m}, {x -> 1 + 2 n, 
  y -> 2 m}, {x -> 1 + 2 n, y -> 1 + 2 m}} *)
```

This states that either both x and y are **even**, both x and y are **odd**, or one is **even** and the other is **odd**. This covers all possible integer pairs.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can just give Mathematica the list of points ( a list of x,y) and it spits out a relation among themselves?

Comment: Like, if I gave then (-4, 0), (-3,0) ...(0,0) ... (0,2), (0,3), (0,4), could it tell me just <code> x-> 2n, y-> 0 </code>.

Comment: Basically I have only access to the minima positions, not the original function.