# Solve returning a solution despite generating a message saying it can't

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I have a method that finds the location of the minima of a function (derived in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173583/give-mathematica-points-in-the-xy-plane-and-find-equation-that-generates-them/173597#173597)).

```
RealPotentialCubic[x_, y_] := Sin[π x]^2 + Sin[π y]^2;
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers], 
  Solve[{D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], x] == 0, 
     D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], y] == 0, 
     D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], {x, 2}] > 0, 
     D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], {y, 2}] > 0}, {x, y}, Reals] // 
   Simplify] /. {C[1] -> n, C[2] -> m}
```

This gives

> ```
> {{x -> 2 n, y -> 2 m}, {x -> 2 n, y -> 1 + 2 m}, 
>  {x -> 1 + 2 n, y -> 2 m}, {x -> 1 + 2 n, y -> 1 + 2 m}}
> ```

However if I try:

```
RealPotentialTriangular[x_, y_] := 
  Sin[π x]^2 + Sin[π (Sqrt[3] y - x)/2]^2 + Sin[π (Sqrt[3] y + x)/2]^2;
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers], 
  Solve[{D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], x] == 0, 
     D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], y] == 0, 
     D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], {x, 2}] > 0, 
     D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], {y, 2}] > 0}, {x, y}, Reals] // 
   Simplify] /. {C[1] -> n, C[2] -> m}
```

it still gives me an answer,

> ```
> {{x -> 2 n, y -> (2 m)/Sqrt[3]}, {x -> 1 + 2 n, y -> (1 + 2 m)/Sqrt[3]}}
> ```

but it also the error message

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

Why? What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minor change in the code gives a better answer for the first computation and eliminates the error message from the second.

```
RealPotentialCubic[x_, y_] := Sin[π x]^2 + Sin[π y]^2;
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers], 
  Solve[{D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], x] == 0, 
    D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], y] == 0, 
    D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], {x, 2}] > 0, 
    D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], {y, 2}] > 0} // Simplify, {x, y}, Reals] // 
  Simplify] /. {C[1] -> n, C[2] -> m}
(* {{x -> n, y -> m}} *)

RealPotentialTriangular[x_, y_] := 
  Sin[π x]^2 + Sin[π (Sqrt[3] y - x)/2]^2 + Sin[π (Sqrt[3] y + x)/2]^2;
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers], 
  Solve[{D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], x] == 0, 
    D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], y] == 0, 
    D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], {x, 2}] > 0, 
    D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], {y, 2}] > 0} // Simplify, {x, y}, Reals] // 
  Simplify] /. {C[1] -> n, C[2] -> m}
(* {{x -> 2 n, y -> (2 m)/Sqrt[3]}, {x -> 1 + 2 n, y -> (1 + 2 m)/Sqrt[3]}} *)
```

Consider the first block of code.  Simplifying the argument of `Solve` before actually executing `Solve` allows it to provide a simpler answer that is equivalent to the answer shown in the question.  Breaking the calculation into pieces perhaps provides a clearer picture.

```
cu = {D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], x] == 0, D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], y] == 0, 
 D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], {x, 2}] > 0, D[RealPotentialCubic[x, y], {y, 2}] > 0}
(* {2 π Cos[π x] Sin[π x] == 0,  2 π Cos[π y] Sin[π y] == 0, 
    2 π^2 Cos[π x]^2 - 2 π^2 Sin[π x]^2 > 0, 2 π^2 Cos[π y]^2 - 2 π^2 Sin[π y]^2 > 0} *)
```

and applying

```
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers], 
  Solve[cu, {x, y}, Reals] // Simplify] /. {C[1] -> n, C[2] -> m}
```

then gives the result in the question.  However, if `Simplify` first is applied to the argument of `Solve`

```
cu // Simplify
(* {Sin[2 π x] == 0, Sin[2 π y] == 0, Cos[2 π x] > 0, Cos[2 π y] > 0} *)
```

applying

```
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers], 
  Solve[%, {x, y}, Reals] // Simplify] /. {C[1] -> n, C[2] -> m}
```

gives the simpler expression above  in this answer.

Now turn to the second block of code in the queston, which throws an error message before returning the correct answer.  `Solve` alone,

```
Solve[{D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], x] == 0, 
  D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], y] == 0, 
  D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], {x, 2}] > 0, 
  D[RealPotentialTriangular[x, y], {y, 2}] > 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

again generates the error message and **returns unevaluated**.  Then, `Simplify` changes the argument to a form that `Solve` can handle, whereupon it returns the correct answer without difficulty.  To illustrate, the actual argument of `Solve` after `RealPotentialTriangular[x, y]` is expanded is some eight lines of code long.  However, applying `Simplify` to it yields the much simpler

```
{(2 Cos[π x] + Cos[Sqrt[3] π y]) Sin[π x] == 0, Cos[π x] Sin[Sqrt[3] π y] == 0, 
 Cos[π x] (2 Cos[π x] + Cos[Sqrt[3] π y]) > 2 Sin[π x]^2, Cos[π x] Cos[Sqrt[3] π y] > 0}
```

which `Solve` can handle without difficulty, giving the desired result.

In summary, with the second block of code in the question, `Solve` first fails and returns unevaluated.  Then `Simplify` transforms the argument of `Solve` into a form that it can handle, and `Solve` then automatically runs a second time, giving the desired result.  However, with the corresponding modified code in  this answer, `Solve` works the first time, and does not throw an error message.

**Addendum**

The OP asked in a comment below whether `Solve` could obtain solutions as above for another function:

```
RealPotentialQuasicrystal[x_, y_] := 
  Sin[π x]^2 + Sin[π (y - x)/2]^2 + Sin[π y]^2 + Sin[π (y + x)/2]^2
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers], 
  Solve[{D[RealPotentialQuasicrystal[x, y], x] == 0, 
         D[RealPotentialQuasicrystal[x, y], y] == 0, 
         D[RealPotentialQuasicrystal[x, y], {x, 2}] > 0, 
         D[RealPotentialQuasicrystal[x, y], {y, 2}] > 0} // Simplify, 
        {x, y}, Reals] // Simplify] /. {C[1] -> n, C[2] -> m}
```

Unfortunately, it returns unevaluated.  However, replacing `Solve` by `Reduce` does work.

```
(* (x == 1 + 2 n && (y == 2 m || y == 1 + 2 m)) || 
   (x == 2 m && (y == 2 n || y == 1 + 2 n)) *)
```

If desired, this set of equations can be transformed to rules.

```
% // LogicalExpand // ToRules // List
(* {{x -> 2 m, y -> 2 n}, {x -> 2 m, y -> 1 + 2 n}, 
    {x -> 1 + 2 n, y -> 2 m}, {x -> 1 + 2 n, y -> 1 + 2 m}} *)
```

Note that this is equivalent to `{x -> n, y -> m}`, as can be verified as follows.  Let `arg` be the first argument of `Solve` (or `Reduce`) above.  Then,

```
FullSimplify[arg /. {x -> n, y -> m}, (n | m) ∈ Integers]
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: How do I know what form of the equation Solve can or cannot handle?

Comment: For example, if I now appy to a new function <code>RealPotentialQuasicrystal[x_, y_] := 
  Sin[\[Pi] x]^2 + Sin[\[Pi] (y - x)/2]^2 + Sin[\[Pi] y]^2 + 
   Sin[\[Pi] (y + x)/2]^2;</code>, it throws again an error message. How do I know that the error is due to the fact that Solve cannot manage it, or to the fact that there is no solution?

Comment: Sorry did you actually manage to Solve the RealPotentialQuasicrystal functio in my comment above? I am putting Simplify everywhere and it still says it can'd solve it

Comment: @SuperCiocia  No, my earlier attempt with `Solve` contained a typo.  So, I replaced `Solve` by `Reduce`, which worked fine.  See the addendum to my answer above.

Comment: You can also use `Solve[eqn,var,Reals,Method -> Reduce]`.

Comment: Thanks. I was surpised that the function had solutions, but then I realised I mstyped it: the one I actualy wanted was <code>RealPotentialQuasicrystal[x_, y_] := 
 Sin[\[Pi] x]^2 + Sin[\[Pi] (y - x)/Sqrt[2]]^2 + Sin[\[Pi] y]^2 + 
  Sin[\[Pi] (y + x)/Sqrt[2]]^2</code>, so you see there's actually a root(2). I cannot solve this with any Reduce or Solve, I'm assuming it cannot actually find solutions because of the nature of the function?

Comment: @SuperCiocia  That is correct.  The presence of irrational numbers appears to be the problem.  `FindRoot` can find numerous individual roots, of course.